# Rowwise summing factor columns in dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a tibble called `ehp30` with 13 columns which correspond to the answers of a questionnaire (11 columns) by patients at a certain followup timepoint. First row is (with fake data):

```
   Pat_TNO AssNo    eSocialEvents eJobsAtHome eStandingUp eSittingDown eWalking  eExercise eAppetite eSleep    eHadToLieDown eUnableToDo eUnableToCope
     <dbl> <fct>    <fct>         <fct>       <fct>       <fct>        <fct>     <fct>     <fct>     <fct>     <fct>         <fct>       <fct>        
 1    1234 baseline Often         Often       Sometimes   Sometimes    Sometimes Often     Sometimes Often     Often         Often       Sometimes
```

I want to mutate a new column on the end called 'pain' which is the sum of the values from the 11 columns between `eSocialEvents` and `eUnableToCope`. The levels are:

```
 "Never"     "Rarely"    "Sometimes" "Often"     "Always"
```

which are effectively numbered 1-5, so the sum of the first row should be 39.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert to `numeric`, and then use `rowSums`:

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("e"), as.numeric),
         rowS = rowSums(select(., starts_with("e")))
```

Answer (score 0):

With some sample data in a reproducible format

```
dd <- read.table(text="Pat_TNO AssNo    eSocialEvents eJobsAtHome eStandingUp eSittingDown eWalking  eExercise eAppetite eSleep    eHadToLieDown eUnableToDo eUnableToCope
  1    1234 baseline Often         Often       Sometimes   Sometimes    Sometimes Often     Sometimes Often     Often         Often       Sometimes   
  2    4567 baseline Always        Often       Sometimes   Sometimes    Sometimes Often     Sometimes Often     Often         Often       Sometimes", header=TRUE)
```

You can use `dplyr` to sum the rows with the given level order

```
levels <- c("Never", "Rarely", "Sometimes", "Often", "Always")

dd %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(score=sum(match(c_across(starts_with("e")), levels))) %>% 
  select(AssNo, score)
```

Here we use `match()` to look up the index of the value in the `levels` vector. If all the columns are already factors with all the levels set in the correct order, you could just use `as.numeric` on the factor values to convert them to integers